# Checking if a HKEY HANDLE is valid?

Tags: c++, registry, handle

I'm using a function that essentially does this:

```
HANDLE someHandler;
RegCloseKey((HKEY) someHandler);
```

After the `RegCloseKey()` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`, I check the following:

```
if (someHandler == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{ ..... }
```

But I now see that the above condition is never true. I tried replacing the check of INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE with `null, null pointer` but they all fail. How do I check if the handle is valid or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegCloseKey doesn't change the handle value.  It just closes the handle.  Once it's closed, the variable `someHandler` remember what the handle value was, but it's not useful.  Rather than testing it, you might want to set it to an invalid value:

```
RegCloseKey(someHandler);
someHandler = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

That will keep you from accidentally trying to use it after you've closed it.  This same pattern can apply to dynamic memory, file handles, etc.  You might also consider using a framework designed for C++ that hides some of the details of the resource management for you.  For example, ATL provides an more natural C++ interface for registry access than the C-oriented Windows APIs can offer.