# Is there a Proper way of Checking if an HKEY/PHKEY is Valid?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, registry

```
REGISTRY()
{
    /*HKEY*/m_pRoot = nullptr;
    /*HKEY*/m_pReturnKey = nullptr;
    m_pPath = nullptr;
    m_pValueName = nullptr;
}
~REGISTRY()
{
    if ( m_pReturnKey ) 
    {
        RegCloseKey(m_pReturnKey);
        m_pReturnKey = nullptr;
    }
    if ( m_pRoot ) 
    {
        RegCloseKey(m_pRoot);
        m_pRoot = nullptr;
    }
}
```

I have a class which handles All Registry functions of my applications, I let the Object's Destructor handle the closing of the `HKEY`s (as Shown Above). I have adopted the [answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308973/checking-if-a-hkey-handle-is-valid), but instead of using `HANDLES` I've simply Set the `HKEY`s as `nullptr` during the object's construction and check if it's not `nullptr` during destruction and close it. I'm also using Smart Pointers<`unique_ptr`> when using it to ensure that the Destructor get's called even when it throws an exception.

Since Upon Checking ,when `RegOpenKeyExA` ,`RegCreateKeyExA` , `RegSetValueEx` , or `RegQueryValueExA` returns anything other than `ERROR_SUCCESS` it doesn't do anything to the passed `HKEY` and it remained as a `nullptr`.

Aside from this method is there a proper way to check if a HKEY/PHKEY is active and valid? Scouring the MSDN page on [winreg.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/) provided me nothing, if it's there I might be blind or it's not using a Function Name that is not obvious to an amateur like me.

Comment: If the open/create/etc. succeeded then you should close the key when you're done with it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the way is object is structed is that, When I'm Done with it, then That key would also be not in use,That's why it's in the destructor. The reason I'm asking is that, I'm not sure of the behavior when calling `RegCloseKey` on an Invalid `HKEY`.

Comment: Is it exceptional if opening a registry key fails?  If so then the constructor or opening member function should throw and RAII takes care of the problem.

Comment: The way you know a handle is valid is that you received it from one of the functions (create, open, etc.) that return them. When you're done with it you call `RegCloseKey`. It's that simple. Generally the time between obtaining a handle, using it for whatever you need to do, and closing it is very short, like the span of a single function. If you're keeping them around for so long that you don't know if they are still valid you're probably doing it wrong. Even the remarks for `RegCloseKey` say "Key handles should not be left open any longer than necessary."

Comment: @RetiredNinja The object's Responsibility is as follows, It Checks if the Key is There, if It is then It retrieves/modify a Value ,if not , then It creates a Key, then it Sets a value, Then The object is destroyed. So I'm not keeping them around longer as I need them to be. I wrapped it into an object since I want to ensure the Closure of the `HKEY` during it's destruction, And it's also used in many parts of the app. As I mentioned if this is really the only way to "Check", Since there would be a time when, Only 1 of the HKEY's would be open so the Object should know. Hence the current code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Maybe the proper term for the current Constructor/Destructor would be "I wanted to pass the responsibility of knowing to the Object Itself" .

Comment: That doesn't read like a useful abstraction. If you want an object that cleans up after itself, make its c'tor acquire the resources, and throw if it fails. That way you won't need to deal with setting aside a special value; the object will always hold a valid value, or not exist at all. If acquiring the resource consists of several steps, use a function to encapsulate that logic. Have it return a value of whichever type manages your resources. In short: Make it impossible to construct an object that stores invalid data.

Comment: @IInspectable I though that's exactly what I was doing since, the `HKEY` would only be a Valid `HKEY` when the function that uses it actually returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`, hence they are either Nothing or Valid. Those are only the constructors and destructors not the whole object since I've only wanted to know if there is a "Proper" way in checking if an `HKEY` is valid when using `winreg.h` or is there something Included within the API that I may have missed, as I mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @IInspectable and Let's say I did move the Acquisition of the `HKEY` into the Constructor which would be easy and making it impossible to create the object if it won't have a Valid `HKEY`. It still doesn't answer my question. But Your comment does make sense. Preventing the construction of invalid handles would result into the object not caring if it's valid or not since it would "Always" be valid. But I would still love to know if the only way to know if it's valid HKEY is by simply checking the pointer?

Comment: *"they are either Nothing or Valid"* - That's the issue. Why don't you make it impossible to instantiate a class instance unless the values *are* valid? Once you establish that invariant, there's no more checking required.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sorry if I'm relentless but, Somehow I simply really do want to know if the API really didn't have one in checking if it's actually alive/valid.Since there was an instance that `RegCreateKeyExA` returned `ERROR_SUCCESS` but when the `HKEY` was used , it resulted into an Access Violation, this is when I started moving it into a Class, and asked this question.  I knew it was the `HKEY` since when inspected with the environment it said 'unable to reach invalid memory location'. But your comment has made it's way into my to do list when I refactor it tonight.

Comment: @AzrielElijay "*I simply really do want to know if the API really didn't have one in checking if it's actually alive/valid.*" - there is no API to check that. The API that gives you the handle either succeeds or fails, it is your responsibility to check that condition and ignore the handle on failure. Giving an invalid handle back to the API is undefined behavior, unless documented otherwise.

Comment: @AzrielElijay "*there was an instance that `RegCreateKeyExA` returned `ERROR_SUCCESS` but when the `HKEY` was used , it resulted into an Access Violation*" - the only way that can happen is if either you overwrote the `HKEY` itself in a way that invalidated it, or the other parameters you used alongside the `HKEY` were invalid in some way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That could be it I've had version of the code that  resulted into that error since I refactored it to an object as soon as I've received an Access Violation. Thank you for confirming that `winreg.h`, did not include it, Since the `HKEY` would never be touched unless it returns successfully . So I guess my current approach is good enough, but would be better if the object couldn't be created unless the `HKEY` and all other parameters are valid as IInspectable suggested.

Comment: Thank you for all your Comments Richard Critten , IInspectable, Remy Lebeau!

Comment: Not an answer, but if you use Visual Studio, there's an CRegKey class provided (with ATL): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cregkey-class that's a quite nice registry RAII helper and source is open

Comment: @SimonMourier talk about shooting myself in the foot, but that's life. You win some , and then you lose a lot of time in some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [winreg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/) API doesn't set aside a value that represents an invalid `HKEY` (unlike, say, the [fileapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/), where [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) uses `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` for this purpose). Instead, API calls report whether they succeeded, and only then guarantee to have written an `HKEY` to the location provided by the caller.

If your implementation needs to know whether any given piece of information represents valid data, you'll have to record this information separately. Starting with C++17, [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is the standard tool for this purpose.

A possible solution to your problem could thus be:

```cpp
class REGISTRY
{
    std::optional<HKEY> m_pRoot;
    std::optional<HKEY> m_pReturnKey;
    // ...
}

REGISTRY::~REGISTRY()
{
    if (m_pReturnKey)
    // equivalent to
    // if (m_pReturnKey.has_value())
    {
        RegCloseKey(m_pReturnKey.value());
        m_pReturnKey = {};
    }
    // ...
}
```

`m_pRoot` and `m_pReturnKey` are default-initialized, meaning, they hold a value of type `std::nullopt_t`. The d'tor will observe this, and not do anything. Which solves the problem as stated.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But as my tags stated the project that I'm applying this into is being compiled using MSVC2008SP1 so I'm limited to C++03 with boost 1.5, I would love to move the project to a Higher standard if I could, but Third Party Libraries won't let me. so `std::optional` is out of the question. But that does answer my question plain and simple that the `winreg` API really doesn't have anything to validate an `HKEY` and only does guarantee it's Validity when `ERROR_SUCCESS` is returned.

Comment: @AzrielElijay Well, my bad, I completely ignored the [tag:visual-studio-2008] tag, but I guess *"you'll have to record this information separately"* counts as an answer. Now if you're interested in API design guidance (that'll work with C++any), I'll drop a few notes on how to better structure your code without requiring C++17. That'll be opinionated, strongly at that.

Comment: Your earlier comments to this question made more and more sense the more I thought about it and I've followed your advice and made it impossible to instantiate the class without assurance that it would have an invalid handles or values. As of now I've separated them into Two classes this would make sure that at the very least ensure that any function using the class couldn't instantiate it if it was passed with parameters that would not ensure a proper `HKEY`. Being self taught and all, I'm glad many of you can at least understand my problem.